# Usage of drove off in the following sentence

Tags: verbs, word-usage

> "I'll drive you to the MRT, then," her father said.
>
> After saying goodbye to her mother and promising to come back soon,
>   Naomi got into her father's car, and **drove off** to the main road with
>   him.

What I want to say is: "She got into the car and then her father **drove off** to the main road." I'm not very sure but I think the *with him* implies that her father was the one driving. Or it reads as if Naomi is the one driving the car? (Or **drove off** actually means *left to the place and started heading to X* so it isn't actually a problem?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with that sentence, I would understand that it was Naomi who was driving. Since the subject of your sentence is Naomi, any verbs will be assumed to be her actions.

The easiest way around this would be to simply say

> After saying goodbye to her mother and promising to come back soon, Naomi got into her father's car and **they** drove to the main road.

The *they* removes ambiguity and you don't really need *off*, *drove* will do. To *drive off* brings to mind driving into the sunset, going away with no specific destination in mind. It is rarely<sup>1</sup> used when a destination is specified.

However, as @TrevorD points out, this sounds as if they are driving *towards* the main road. If you want them to drive away on the big road you could write:

> After saying goodbye to her mother and promising to come back soon, Naomi got into her father's car and they drove off *down* the main road.

This brings to mind an image of their driving away into the distance down the big road.

<sup>1</sup><sub>It is actually a relatively common idiom in some parts of the UK where you will hear *I drove off to the store* but I would be surprised to see it written.</sub>

Comment: Funny, that's what I wrote at first. But then I thought changing pronouns (she and they in this case) in the same sentence makes the sentence awkward?

Comment: @janoChen not at all: _She said hello and they turned to look at her_.

Comment: "Drove *to* the main road" sounds to me (in the UK) as if the main road was their *destination*. "drove off to ..." doesn't carry quite the say connotation, but I would probably write "drove off towards ..." or just "drove off" & omit the rest (unless it's relevant to the follwoing passage).

Comment: @TrevorD ah, I kinda thought that's what the OP meant but it might not be. Answer edited, thanks.

Comment: I was about to write exactly what Trevor wrote—unless they do MRT scans on the roads wherever this novel takes place, “drove off to the main road” almost certainly means the wrong thing.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I was imagining a tearful farewell in the yard, and then driving down the driveway or country lane in the direction of the main road. Still, the second version should cover both interpretations.

Comment: I would have used ‘towards’ in that case, that would work.

Answer (score 1):

> Naomi got into her father's car and **they drove** to the main road

changes the focus from Naomi to Naomi and her father.  If you want to keep the focus on Naomi, you can say

> Naomi got into her father's care and she **rode** to the main road with him.